# nested parantheses in function definitions

Tags: java

I am learning java and first program i am making is Hello World. I was able to print it but then i tried to play with it. According to me the below program should not compile but it is compiling and printing Hello World.

```
class Hello { 

    // main: generate some output

    public static void main(String args[]){
    System.out.print(("Hello World"));
  }
}
```

But if i do same thing with main method it is giving me multiple error while compiling.

```
class Hello {

    // main: generate some output

    public static void main((String args[])){
      System.out.print((("Hello World")));
    }
}
```

Here are some of the compile errors for second program:

```
Hello.java:5: error: ';' expected
        public static void main((String args[])){
                                             ^
Hello.java:6: error: illegal start of type
      System.out.print((("Hello World")));
        ^
Hello.java:6: error: ';' expected
      System.out.print((("Hello World")));
```

Can someone explain me why first program is compiled successfully and second one gave error?

Comment: was trying to check how it works. I thought for print method after starting brace we need to give the printing string in double quotes(") only. But this didn't do like that. I am wondering where those extra braces are going? neither they are getting printed nor i am getting error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Any time you write an expression that has a value, you can put part of your expression in parentheses.  So you can say

```
(a + b) * c
```

to tell the compiler to do the addition before the multiplication.  To keep things simple, the rules let you put parentheses anywhere in an expression (well, not exactly *anywhere*, but around any part of the expression that denotes a value), even when they're not necessary.  So you can say

```
a + (b * c)
```

or

```
(((a + b))) * c
```

or

```
(((a)) + (b)) * (c)
```

or

```
System.out.println(("Hello world"));
```

since `"Hello world"` is an expression with a value.

But that applies *only* to expressions, because that's where the ability to add parentheses is needed.  In other places in the syntax, where parentheses are used for something other than an expression (such as a list of parameter names), the syntax doesn't allow for the extra parentheses.  Note that this means you can say

```
max = Math.max((a),(b));
```

but *not*

```
max = Math.max((a,b));
```

because `(a,b)` is not an expression with a single value.

Comment: Nice explanation of the differences!

Comment: []http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/expressions.html  here it says **cadence = 0** is expression so nested braces concept should apply to this also correct?

Comment: but **int (cadence = 0);**  is not working giving compile error only.

Comment: @GauravParek - I think you've found an error in the tutorial. That's not an expression - it's a *variable declarator*. The part after the = is an expression in this case. (BTW, ajb - I was typing a comment about `(a+b)*c` and your answer popped up with the exact same expression.)

Comment: @GauravParek Andy is right on this ... The tricky thing is that you have to study the grammar in a language specification to find out what is considered an "expression" or a "statement" or a "declaration" or whatever.  Things that look the same might not be considered the same thing by the grammar.  And it varies from language to language; an assignment (not a declaration) in C or Java is an expression, but in other languages an assignment is _not_ an expression.

Comment: Thanks now its clear to me.if you happen to any decent tutorial where I can see more about expression would be great since the one i looked seems to have error 

Comment: @ajb: by assignment you mean something like **x=0;** ? As this is expression in Java so nested braces concept should apply to this. but doesn't seem to work. any reasons? **(x=0);** this is what tried.

Comment: @GauravParek `(x=0)` is a valid _expression_, but not every expression is a valid statement.  Only certain kinds of expressions are allowed as complete statements, and it looks like `x=0` is one of the allowed forms but `(x=0)` is not.  See [this section of the language standard](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-14.html#jls-StatementExpression) if you want more information, but be warned that language standards can be hard to follow if you're not used to them.

Answer (score 4):

The syntax for expressions allows nested parantheses.

The syntax for method headers does not. Following the method identifier is a list of formal parameters bracketed by single parantheses.

From the [Java language specification, section 8.4, Method Declarations](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.4):

```
MethodDeclaration:
    MethodHeader MethodBody

MethodHeader:
    MethodModifiersopt TypeParametersopt Result MethodDeclarator Throwsopt

MethodDeclarator:
    Identifier ( FormalParameterList[optional] )
```

Comment: could you please elaborate on this. I am wondering for first program where those extra braces are going?

Comment: The parantheses indicate an order of evaluation within an expression. In this case, they're unnecessary, but allowed.

Comment: @GauravParek What do you mean "where are they going"?  There's no rule that says that the parentheses have to have an impact on your program.  Redundant parentheses are allowed, but only in places where the syntax allows them.

Answer (score 0):

You're messing with how methods are declared by trying to add all those extra parenthesis. Method declarations don't allow it, so your code doesn't compile.

In the code, you're evaluating things rather than defining them - extra parenthesis evaluate fine there, so it doesn't impact the behavior of the code.

Answer (score 0):

well it is just syntax error. in Java this is the proper way to right your class.

```
class Hello { 

// main: generate some output

public static void main(String args[]){
System.out.print(("Hello World"));
} 
}
```

On the second one you added parentheses that cannot be  compiled. syntax error.